# Dumping in-memory database to disk

Tags: database, dump, snapshot, persistent, in-memory

I have created in-memory database(key-value pair) of my own. What is the efficient way to dump  that to disk as a backup. 
I am also doing periodic writes to in-memory database. and i need to provide persistency. 
Is there a file format i can use to just append modified/added records(only flush delta to disk file instead of snapshotting whole database) ?

Comment: Why don't you just use MongoDB for this?

Comment: I know mongoDB provides hybrid approach. however, i want to create back of already existing in-memory data.